# Nginx.conf error 2, virtual host server block not found

Tags: ubuntu-server

trying to setup nginx to serve anarchistparty.org synapse homeserver reverse proxy. Nginx.conf is currently standard install, hasn’t been edited.

`Sudo nginx -t` gives:

> nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/anarchistparty.org"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory) in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:62
>   nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
>
> anarchistparty.org is present in sites-available and symlinked

Answer (score 0):

[source](https://jsephler.co.uk/nginx-failed-2-no-such-file-or-directory-in-etc-nginx-nginx-conf/)

Perhaps you created the symbolic link using relative paths instead of absolute paths, like the author of the source article (and I) did. In this case, the solution is to use absolute paths:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/anarchistparty.org /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Comment: spelling mistake /ect/nginx/sites-enabled/   
corect path.
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/anarchistparty.org /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/